# PostgreSQL installing from source - conflicting types for 'copy_file_range' error

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.5

I'm currently trying to install a previous version of Postgresql from the source code, however after unzipping the tarball and running the "make" command to create the binaries I run into this error:

`copy_fetch.c:161:1: error: conflicting types for ‘copy_file_range’
 copy_file_range(const char *path, off_t begin, off_t end, bool trunc)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from copy_fetch.c:16:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:1110:9: note: previous declaration of ‘copy_file_range’ was here`

I can see on the Postgres message boards there has been talk about renaming copy_file_range(): https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1eWpqd-00067Q-2b%40gemulon.postgresql.org

Does anyone know what steps are needed to resolve this issue? The version of Postgres I am trying to install is 9.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 9.5.11 or a later version where the fix has been applied.

If you insist on using an older version, you'll have to apply [the patch](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=ea4cbf8f1050b490d3040e659598bee63494288d) yourself.